# Add an iOS App to xCode Empty Project for UI Test

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I have Xcode version 7.3 and  I am facing problem with testing my iOS App.

I have created an Empty Project. Then I added a new file as `UI Test Case Class`. There I want to record my steps which I want to test. I know how to record steps,
but I cannot add my ios app to this project, so my app fails to launch.

How i can add my iOS app to my newly created project?

Comment: I want to test my ios app using xcode ui test.to record steps i need to launch my app.but i dont find any way how i can add my app to my xcode project...@Phillip Mills

Comment: @Phillip Mills ... I just create an empty project ... There i add a file for ui test case. Now i want to run my ios app from this project so that i can record steps in my ui test case file..thats all i want to do

Comment: @Phillip Mills i dont have the source i only have the .app ..... How i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to select the UITest Target if not selected, see the attached snapshot

[image: Refer the screen]